# Is there any implementation of Prophet with XGB for forecasting in Python

Tags: python, forecasting, arima, facebook-prophet

I am looking for some similar implementation in Python for the models "prophet_boost", "arima_boost", similar to modeltime implementation in R, for time series forecasting.

- prophet_boost = Prophet + XGB Errors
- arima_boost = AutoARIMA + XGB Errors